# Setting null or empty for @singular list in lombok

Tags: java, lombok

I have a list as

```
@Value
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
class Demo {

    private BigInteger id; 

    @Singular
    private List<String> name;
}
```

I have some data added in the name list. Now I want to set it to empty or null. How can I achieve it?
As per my understanding if I m using @Singular annotation it makes the list immutable.

I m using Java with Lombok.

Answer (score 7):

> As per my understanding if I m using @Singular annotation it makes the
>   list immutable.

It makes the list in the `Demo` instance immutable. It does not make the list immutable in the builder; it simply changes the API of the builder.

From [the documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder#singular):

> with the `@Singular` annotation, lombok will treat that builder node
>   as a collection, and it generates 2 'adder' methods instead of a
>   'setter' method

As for emptying the list,

> A 'clear' method is also generated.

In your case, `clearNames` (the list field should be called `names`, not `name`, otherwise Lombok complains).

---

If you want a mutable instance, don't use `@Singular`

Comment: Remark: You cannot set the list to `null` when using `@Singular`. Don't use `@Singular` if you really need that.

Answer (score 2):

> As per my understanding if I m using @Singular annotation it makes the
>   list immutable

No, Lambok just create method for single add element, for you class (I strongly recommend change name to names). You just need to call method "clearNames"

```
@Value
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
class Demo {

    private BigInteger id; 

    @Singular
    private List<String> names;
}
```

Lambok generate following builder

```
public static class UserBuilder {
       private BigInteger id; 
       private ArrayList<String> names;

       UserBuilder() {
       }    


       public User.UserBuilder name(String name) {
           if (this.names == null) this.names = new ArrayList<String>();
           this.names.add(name);
           return this;
       }

       public User.UserBuilder names(Collection<? extends String> names) {
           if (this.names == null) this.names = new ArrayList<String>();
           this.names.addAll(names);
           return this;
       }

       public User.UserBuilder clearNames() {
           if (this.names != null)
               this.names.clear();

           return this;
       }

       ...    
       public User build() {
           ...
       }

       public String toString() {
           ...
       }
   }
```